# Create new column with reformated date

Tags: postgresql

I have a column named 'date' formatted as date-type with values like
2007-08-24T00:00:00Z

I would like to populate a new column called date2 with a reformatted string like
August 24th, 2007

Below is my attempt at this. What am I missing?

UPDATE myTable SET date2 = date_part('Mon DD, YYYY',date);

Comment: Dates should be stored in columns using [one of the built-in date/time types](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/datatype-datetime.html) and converted to a particular string format only when `SELECT`ing them out.

Comment: Also, `date_part` doesn't take a format string as its first argument, or an already formatted date as its second argument, so doesn't come close to meeting your stated requirements. See http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-EXTRACT

Comment: @IMSoP - date_part has worked for me with a formatted date as 2nd argument. For example - UPDATE myTable SET date2 = date_part('year',date); - works and creates a new column with just the year from the date column

Comment: Then maybe that column is not, in fact, a formatted string - what is the type of the column?

Comment: It is already a date-type column..

Comment: Then the first sentence of your question is incorrect; the column is not "with default formatting" - it has no formatting at all, in the database, only when you select it. I will add an answer.

Answer (score 1):

As noted in the comments, if your column is [one of the built-in date/time types](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/datatype-datetime.html) - `date`, `timestamp`, etc - then it is not stored in the database with any particular string format, but as abstract data. This is the only way you should ever store dates in the DB, as it allows you to perform [a whole range of operations](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-datetime.html) directly on the data.

To format such a value, you apply an appropriate formatting **when you select the data**. I would strongly recommend against storing this formatted string anywhere - it adds no value to your database, since any format can be calculated at any time, but does mean you have duplicated data to manage in future.

The [formatting functions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-formatting.html) take a slightly unusual specifier format; in your case, I believe you want `'FMMonth Dth, YYYY'`:

```
 SELECT
    to_char("date", 'FMMonth Dth, YYYY') as formatted_date
 FROM
    my_table;
```

As an alternative trick, if you happen to be using PHP, you can select the date out as a Unix timestamp, and then use PHP functions to format that:

```
 SELECT
    extract(epoch from "date") as unix_date
 FROM
    my_table;
```

Answer (score 0):

this does the trick

UPDATE myTable SET date2 = to_char(date,'Month DD, YYYY')

Comment: Now you are storing a `date` as an `varchar`. That is a really bad thing.

Comment: Why is that bad? I just want to use it as text. It will serve no quantitative purpose

Comment: It is bad because it duplicates the information, that is already present in the database.

Answer (score 0):

If you are for some reason fed up with calling the date formatting functions, you can put your `extract()` or `to_char()` into a function, or create an appropriate view on your table.